# Adjust X Scale in highchart to display proper ratio

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scale

[image]

Base on image, Each X value had 20 point different
and the line should display as straight line.

But Since I add 2 value which is 1025.96 and 1026.50 (as show with color background on the right table) and it still use the same scale for each number so the line graph not straight.

How can I adjust this 2 point show in the graph and make it plot proper scale? (Show straight line).

```
  $(document).ready(function() {


    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2950',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 45
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Strategy 2, Long C950',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        credits: {
enabled: false
  },
        xAxis: {
  title: {
                text: 'SET50 Index ณ วันหมดอายุ'
            },
   categories:     [925,945,965,985,1005,1025,1025.96,1026.5,1045,1065,1085,1105,1125]

        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Profit / Loss (Bath)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +' บาท';
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [
        {name: 'Long C950', data:     [-15300,-15300,-12300,-8300,-4300,-300,-107.99999999999,0,3700,7700,11700,15700,19700]}
        ]

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code to see, I can't be sure, but I suspect you are specifying xAxis categories. This will always equally space the x axis parameters rather than plotting them to scale.

Instead, you should specify your series data like this:

```
data:[ [925,-15300],[945,-15300] ]
```

This specifies x,y value pairs. You can also do:

```
data:[ {x:925,y:-15300},{x:945,y:-15300} ]
```

The second option allows you to set other point attributes such as colour etc.

Comment: I was right. Remove the categories in the xAxis and specify your data as suggested in my first example. I only showed they the first two points, but you can specify all your points this way.

Comment: This is the chart after adjust, it look good https://dl.dropbox.com/u/67227764/scale2.png  but they plot only 4 value on X scale, which is 950, 1000, 1050 and 1100, How can I set it to plot at least 8 value on X? Is it possible?

Comment: I just found it. tickInterval:20,